# Use reflection to deserialize content of game throws MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, xml, xna, deserialization, content-pipeline

I have developped a custom XMLDeserializer which uses reflection to deserialize the content of my game (.xml). But I have an error that i don't figure it out when the content pipeline is compiling:

> Error 1    Building content threw MethodAccessException: Attempt by
>   security transparent method
>   'DynamicClass.ReflectionEmitUtils(System.Object)' to access security
>   critical method 'System.Reflection.Assembly.get_PermissionSet()'
>   failed.
>
> Assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is marked with the
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security
>   transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent
>   by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

The error doesn't occur if I comment out this code :

```cs
// Add item to the collection
if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(collectionType))
{
   collectionType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(collectionObject, new[] { itemObject });
}
else if (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(collectionType))
{
   collectionType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(collectionObject, new[] { itemType, itemObject });
}
```

It seems that my assembly does not have the permission to call code in mscorlib assembly.
If i call my method in a console application, it works.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since `IList` and `IDictionary` are generic, maybe you are not locating the correct method, or are trying to pass the wrong types to them? Their `Add` methods will be strongly typed to their generic type. You might also be finding the wrong `Add` overload since you did not specify the parameter types. You might wish to do something like:

```
// Add item to the collection
if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(collectionType)) {
   var addMethod = collectionType.GetMethod("Add", new[] { itemObject.GetType() });
   if (addMethod == null)
      throw new SerializationException("Failed to find expected IList.Add method.");
   addMethod.Invoke(collectionObject, new[] { itemObject });
} else if (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(collectionType)) {
   var addMethod = collectionType.GetMethod("Add", new[] { typeof(Type), itemObject.GetType()}
   if (addMethod == null)
      throw new SerializationException("Failed to find expected IDictionary.Add method.");
   addMethod.Invoke(collectionObject, new[] { itemType, itemObject });
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. The problem is not the code itself. Because if a call my 'Deserialize' method inside a console application, it works. But if i call it from ContentPipelineExtension project, it doesn't work :(